# Understanding Conv2D and LSTM

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to predict next image. So I am using Conv2D and LSTM instead of ConvLSTM2D. The reason is I want to understand every step as I am a beginner. My questions are:
1) I wanted to write a generator method that will return X and y. I think the shape of X will be (number of samples, timesteps, height, width, channels) but I am not sure about the shape of y. (For example, if we want to predict temperature from a dataset, then in the generator method the shape of X will be (number of samples, timesteps, number of features) and the shape of y will be (number of samples,).)
2) In the network architecture, initially (in the Con2D part) the input shape will be 5D tensor (number of samples, timesteps, height, width, channels). Then in the LSTM part the input shape will be 3D tensor (number of samples, timesteps, height*width*channels). As I am predicting images, should I use Reshape(height, width, channels) at the end of the LSTM?
Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, (5, 5)), input_shape=(None, 512, 512, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, (5, 5))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256, (5, 5))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(256, (5, 5))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(512, (5, 5))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(512, (5, 5))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3))))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))


model.add(LSTM(units=512, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dense(262144, activation='linear'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((512,512,1))))
model.summary()

def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
          shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):
    if max_index is None:
        max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
    i = min_index + lookback
    while 1:
        if shuffle:
            rows = np.random.randint(
                min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
        else:
            if i + batch_size >= max_index:
                i = min_index + lookback
            rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
            i += len(rows)

        samples = np.zeros((len(rows), lookback // step, data.shape[1], data.shape[2], data.shape[3]))
        targets = np.zeros((len(rows), 1, data.shape[1], data.shape[2], data.shape[3]))
        for j, row in enumerate(rows):
            indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
            samples[j] = data[indices]
            targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay]
        yield samples, targets

lookback = 3
step = 1
delay = 1
batch_size = 2

train_gen = generator(image_dataset,
                  lookback=lookback,
                  delay=delay,
                  min_index=0,
                  max_index=19,
                  shuffle=False,
                  step=step, 
                  batch_size=batch_size)

val_gen = generator(image_dataset,
                lookback=lookback,
                delay=delay,
                min_index=20,
                max_index=29,
                step=step,
                batch_size=batch_size)


val_steps = (29 - 20 - lookback) // batch_size

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr = 0.001), loss='mae')

history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                          steps_per_epoch=10,
                          epochs=5,
                          validation_data=val_gen,
                          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Thanks in advance !